# Renderizando sempre todo o código, ao mudar Estado!

Tags: react, react-hooks

To com essa bronca, eu inicio gerando esse array com as 60 posições em branco (inicialmente)

```
let [list, setList] = useState(Array(60).fill(""))
```

Daí com esse array servirá para gerar todos os 60 "botoões" em cada passada do .map(item.,index).  como abaixo:

```
list.map((item, index) => (
     <NumerosParaMarcar index={index} key={index} item={item} />
))
```

**O componente:** Cada botão (número)

```
    const NumerosParaMarcar = (props) => {

    console.log('=== ', props.index)

    return (
        < TouchableOpacity
            delayPressIn={0}
            onPress={() => { marcaNumero(props.index) }}
        >
            <ImageBackground
                style={stylesNumero(props.item).image}
                source={Params.imagemBolaBranca}
            >
                <Text style={stylesNumero(props.item).textNumero}>{(props.index + 1) <= 9 ? "0" + (props.index + 1) : (props.index + 1)}</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
        </TouchableOpacity  >
    )
}
```

**Função MarcaNumero**

```
const marcaNumero = (index) => {


    let numero = (index + 1) <= 9 ? "0" + (index + 1) : (index + 1)

    console.log('inicio ', numero)

    //-- REGISTRO O NUMERO MARCADO NA POSIÇÃO DO ARRAY
    let updateArray = list.map((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex === index ? (item == "" ? numero.toString() : "") : item.toString())

    //-- SEPARO SOMENTE OS QUE TEM NUMEROS!
    numerosMarcados = updateArray.filter(numero => numero !== "")

    let num = numerosMarcados.length
    if (num > qtdMaximoMarcar) {
        setQtdMarcadas(num - 1)
        Toast.showWithGravity('Todos os números já foram marcados ', Toast.LONG, Toast.CENTER)
        return;
    }

    atualizaTituloMsgMarcados()

    setNumerosList(numerosMarcados)
    setQtdMarcadas(num)
    setList(updateArray)

    console.log('fim', numerosList)

}
```

ao mudar setNumerosList(), também está executando todo o código novamente..

```
setNumerosList(numerosMarcados)
```

**Codigo principal, onde monto os compomentes**

```
 return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.layout}>

        <View style={[styles.headerRestaMarcar]}>
            <View style={styles.viewtextFaltaMArca} >
                <Text style={stylesTextoRestaMarcar(qtdMarcadas, qtdMaximoMarcar).textoRestaMarcar}>{msgRestaMarcar}</Text>
            </View>
            <BotaoMarcar />
        </View>


        <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flexDirection: "row",
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                elevation: 6,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                margin: 5,
                borderRadius: 10,
                padding: 5
            }}
        >

            {

                list.map((item, index) => (
                    <NumerosParaMarcar index={index} key={index} item={item} />
                ))
            }

        </ScrollView>

        {qtdMarcadas >= qtdMaximoMarcar && <BotaoSalvarJogada />}

    </SafeAreaView >

);
```

e Fica lindo até aqui, anexei a tela pra vcs terem uma ideia,

ps... reparem nesse trecho:

```
<ImageBackground
   style={stylesNumero(props.item).image}
   source={Params.imagemBolaBranca}
 >
```

eu passo o estado atual do numero dentro do array.. para verificar se está preenchido ou nao.. caso esteja preenchido, eu modifico a cor da letra, para marcar o numero clicado pelo usuario.

a logica entre marcar e desmarcar, quantidade de numeros já marcados.. etc. está funcionando que é uma blz.. tirando o fato de ter que redenrizar tudo de novo ta tudo OKK!!

abronca é que fica lento demais, leva uns 2 segundos. Daí o usuario terá q marcar 12 números, fica muito ruim... sem falar que criei uma forma do app, jogar sozinho para o usuario, sugerir jogadas.. ta levando 12 segundos pra preencher tudo, devido essa renderização desnecessária .

**A BRONCA:**

Daí sei que ao alterar uma posição do array faz com que ele processe novamente, porém eu preciso que somente altere o estado do determinado botão!

A bronca é que quando clico no botão (numero) eu altero (preencho) a posição no array, e nessa modificação de estado é que o app roda todo o código novamente, renderizando todos os botões de 1 a 60 , conforme o array (list), ja com as posições preenchidas. esse preenchimento, afeta a cor do numero e a opacidade da imagem (bola)... eu passo o conteudo da posicao do array para
o styled, e caso essa passado do parametro contenho um numero (ou seja) esteja preenchido... automaticamente eu troco a cor da letra para vermelho por exemplo.

Ao clicar em algum número, eu preencho na posição do número ou seja , caso fosse o numero 4

```
["","","","04","","".... 60x]
```

número 07

["","","","04","","","07".... 60x]

Tentei ja useMemo(), useEffect().. tentei fazer o controle individual de cada botão, mas ainda n consegui resolver a bronca...

espero ter sido claro, obrigado!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código completo:**

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView,
    ImageBackground,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';

import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
import { Parse } from 'parse/react-native';
const Params = require('../bin/Parametros')
const Utils = require('../bin/utils')

const MarcarCartelaScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const qtdMaximoMarcar = Params.qtdMaximoMarcar
    const qtdNumerosCartela = Params.qtdNumerosCartela

    const [numeroUm, setNumeroUm] = useState("")

    const [msgRestaMarcar, setMsgRestaMarcar] = useState("RESTAM " + qtdMaximoMarcar + " NÚMEROS!");
    const [qtdMarcadas, setQtdMarcadas] = useState(0)

    const [alterouSaldo, setAlterouSaldo] = useState(true)

    let [list, setList] = useState(Array(qtdNumerosCartela).fill(""))
    const [numerosList, setNumerosList] = useState([])
    let numerosMarcados = []

    //alterouSaldo && Utils.atualizaSaldoUsuario(navigation)

    const zeraMarcacoes = () => {
        setList(Array(qtdNumerosCartela).fill(""))
        setQtdMarcadas(0)
        atualizaTituloMsgMarcados();
    }

    const salvarJogada = async () => {

        let saldoAtaual = Params.saldoUsuarioDecimal - Params.valorJogada
        if (saldoAtaual < 0) {
            Alert.alert('Atenção!', 'Saldo insuficiente para registrar esta jogada, faça uma recarga e concorra. ', [{ text: 'Ok' }]);
            return;
        }

        const myNewObject = new Parse.Object('jogos');
        myNewObject.set('jogo', numerosList);
        myNewObject.set('usuario', Parse.User.current());

        const usuario = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Parse.User.current()));
        let User = new Parse.Object('_User');
        User.set('objectId', usuario.objectId);
        User.set('saldo', saldoAtaual);

        try {

            await myNewObject.save();
            await User.save();

            Toast.showWithGravity('Sua jogada foi registrada. Boa sorte! ', Toast.LONG, Toast.CENTER);

            zeraMarcacoes()

            Params.saldoUsuarioDecimal = saldoAtaual
            setAlterouSaldo(true)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            Toast.showWithGravity('Algum erro ocorreu, tente mais tarde! ', Toast.LONG, Toast.CENTER);
            return;
        }

    }

    const atualizaTituloMsgMarcados = () => {

        // console.log('---', numerosMarcados.length)
        let restam = qtdMaximoMarcar - numerosMarcados.length
        // console.log('resta ---', restam)

        let msg = restam > 1 && "RESTAM " + restam + " NÚMEROS!"
        msg = restam == 1 ? "RESTA 1 NÚMERO" : msg
        msg = restam == 0 ? numerosMarcados.toString().split(",").join(" ") : msg
        setMsgRestaMarcar(msg)

    }

    const marcarAleatorio = () => {

        setTimeout(function () {

            let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * qtdNumerosCartela + 1)
            let numero = (num) <= 9 ? "0" + num : num

            let index = num - 1;
            if (numerosMarcados.indexOf(numero) > 0) {
                marcarAleatorio()
                return;
            }

            let updateArray = list.map((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex === index ? (item == "" ? numero.toString() : "") : item.toString())

            //-- SEPARO SOMENTE OS QUE TEM NUMEROS!
            numerosMarcados = updateArray.filter(numero => numero !== "")
            list[index] = numero

            setNumerosList(numerosMarcados)
            atualizaTituloMsgMarcados()

            if (numerosMarcados.length < qtdMaximoMarcar) {
                marcarAleatorio()
            } else {
                setNumerosList(numerosMarcados)
                setQtdMarcadas(numerosMarcados.length)
            }

        }, 0);

    }

    const marcaNumero = (index) => {


        let numero = (index + 1) <= 9 ? "0" + (index + 1) : (index + 1)

        console.log('inicio ', numero)

        //-- REGISTRO O NUMERO MARCADO NA POSIÇÃO DO ARRAY
        let updateArray = list.map((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex === index ? (item == "" ? numero.toString() : "") : item.toString())

        //-- SEPARO SOMENTE OS QUE TEM NUMEROS!
        numerosMarcados = updateArray.filter(numero => numero !== "")

        let num = numerosMarcados.length
        if (num > qtdMaximoMarcar) {
            setQtdMarcadas(num - 1)
            Toast.showWithGravity('Todos os números já foram marcados ', Toast.LONG, Toast.CENTER)
            return;
        }

        atualizaTituloMsgMarcados()

        setNumerosList(numerosMarcados)
        setQtdMarcadas(num)
        setList(updateArray)

        console.log('fim', numerosList)

    }

    const marcarCartela = () => {
        marcarAleatorio()
    }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     //alterouSaldo && Utils.atualizaSaldoUsuario(navigation)
    //     console.log('uese effect alterasaldo')

    // }, [alterouSaldo]);



    const NumerosParaMarcar = (props) => {

        console.log('=== ', props.index)

        return (
            < TouchableOpacity
                delayPressIn={0}
                onPress={() => { marcaNumero(props.index) }}
            >
                <ImageBackground
                    style={stylesNumero(props.item).image}
                    source={Params.imagemBolaBranca}
                >
                    <Text style={stylesNumero(props.item).textNumero}>{(props.index + 1) <= 9 ? "0" + (props.index + 1) : (props.index + 1)}</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
            </TouchableOpacity  >
        )
    }

    const BotaoSalvarJogada = () => {
        return (
            <Animatable.View
                style={styles.footer}
                animation="bounceIn">
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.btSalvarJogada}
                    onPress={() => { salvarJogada() }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.textBtSalvarJogada}>SALVAR JOGADA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animatable.View>
        )
    }

    const BotaoMarcar = () => {

        return (

            <Animatable.View
                style={styles.viewbtMarcar}
                animation="tada">

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.btMarcar}
                    onPress={() => { marcarCartela() }}>

                    <Animatable.Text animation="pulse" easing="ease-out" iterationCount="infinite"
                        style={{
                            alignContent: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            fontSize: 55,
                            textAlign: 'center'
                        }}></Animatable.Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </Animatable.View>
        )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        //!mostraBtMarcar && setMostraBtMarcar(true);
        console.log('GERAL - MARCAR CATERLA')

    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.layout}>

            <View style={[styles.headerRestaMarcar]}>
                <View style={styles.viewtextFaltaMArca} >
                    <Text style={stylesTextoRestaMarcar(qtdMarcadas, qtdMaximoMarcar).textoRestaMarcar}>{msgRestaMarcar}</Text>
                </View>
                <BotaoMarcar />
            </View>


            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                    elevation: 6,
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    margin: 5,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    padding: 5
                }}
            >

                {

                    list.map((item, index) => (
                        <NumerosParaMarcar index={index} key={index} item={item} />
                    ))
                }

            </ScrollView>

            {qtdMarcadas >= qtdMaximoMarcar && <BotaoSalvarJogada />}

        </SafeAreaView >

    );
};

// export default React.memo(MarcarCartelaScreen);
export default MarcarCartelaScreen;

const stylesTextoRestaMarcar = (qtdM, qtdMaximoMarcar) => StyleSheet.create({
    textoRestaMarcar: {
        marginTop: 6,
        opacity: qtdM >= qtdMaximoMarcar ? 0.8 : 0.7,
        fontSize: 25,
        color: qtdM >= qtdMaximoMarcar ? "#FFF" : "#FFF",
        textAlign: qtdM >= qtdMaximoMarcar ? "center" : "left",
        fontFamily: 'Caramel Sweets',
    },
})

const stylesNumero = (item) => StyleSheet.create({

    textNumero: {
        fontSize: 18,
        // marginTop: 13,
        marginTop: item === "" ? 13 : 10,
        fontFamily: 'Caramel Sweets',
        color: item !== "" ? "#ff8080" : "#05375a",
        fontFamily: item === "" ? 'Caramel Sweets' : null,
        // opacity: item !== "" ? 1 : 0.8,

    },
    // textNumero: {
    //     fontSize: item !== "" ? 21 : 18,
    //     marginTop: item !== "" ? 13 : 10,
    //     fontFamily: item !== "" ? 'Caramel Sweets' : null,
    //     color: item !== "" ? "#ff8080" : "#05375a",
    //     opacity: item !== "" ? 1 : 0.8,

    // },

    image: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 45,
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        opacity: item !== "" ? 0.6 : 0.8,
        // background: item ? `url(${bolaBranca})` : `url(${bolaMarcada})`,
    }

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    layout: {
        alignItems: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 10,
    },

    header: {
        width: "100%",
        // backgroundColor: '#FF8C00', //Params.corPrimary,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        height: 60,
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
    headerRestaMarcar: {
        elevation: 6,
        margin: 4,
        backgroundColor: "#314968",
        paddingLeft: 10,
        height: 60,
        width: "98%",
        // marginBottom: 20,
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderRadius: 5,
    },

    textoHeader: {
        color: '#CCC',
        fontSize: 17,
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    footer: {
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        position: 'absolute', //Here is the trick
        bottom: 20,
    },
    btSalvarJogada: {
        elevation: 6,
        width: '70%',
        height: 70,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "#FF9800",
        borderRadius: 25,
        borderColor: '#05375a',
        borderWidth: 4,
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    textBtSalvarJogada: {
        marginTop: 10,
        color: '#05375a',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'Caramel Sweets'
    },

    viewtextFaltaMArca: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "center",
    },

    viewMsgTitulo: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        // backgroundColor:"red"
    },

    viewbtFecharHead: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "center",
        alignContent: "flex-end",
        alignItems: "flex-end"
    },

    viewbtMarcar: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        // backgroundColor: "#FFF000",
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        marginRight: 5
    },
    btMarcar: {
        alignContent: "center",
        alignSelf: "center",
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

});
```

**Novo código...**

```html
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const ButtonDefault = styled.Text`
    color: ${props => props.status ? '#ff8080' : '#05375a'}
    margin-top: 13px;
    fontFamily: 'Caramel Sweets';
    font-size: 18px;
`;

const Button = React.memo((props) =>
    <>
        {console.log("===", props.index)}

        <ButtonDefault {...props} />
    </>
);

const MarcarCartelaScreen = () => {

    console.log('Rodando pagina');

    const [list, setList] = React.useState(Array(60).fill(false))

    const handleOnClick = React.useCallback((index) => {

        console.log("---------------------------cliquei ", index);

        let item = [...list];
        item[index] = !item[index];
        setList(item);

    }, [list]);

    return (

        <View>

            {
                list.map((i, x) =>
                    <Button
                        // onClick={e => handleOnClick(e, x)}
                        onPress={e => handleOnClick(x)}
                        status={i}
                        index={x}
                        key={x}>
                        {(x + 1)}
                    </Button>
                )}

        </View>

    )


};

export default MarcarCartelaScreen;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acontece mesmo isso que tu descreveu porque é reativo a partir de qualquer atualização ele monta de novo o componente e executa todas as funções. Uma maneira é utilizando useCallback e memo pra diminuir e também gerar o array de itens fora acho que melhora. Tem que montar na perguntar um exemplo mínino faltou os componentes pra dá uma melhor explicação

Comment: Eu usaria um objeto de array acho que ficaria melhor e o botão tem que colocar o código

Comment: Massa galera, vou editar a pergunta pra tentar melhorar...

Comment: não sei se piorei minha situação :D valeu!! modifiquei.

Comment: Como está o código da função `marcaNumero` ?

Comment: Além do código do `marcaNumero`, como o Isac disse, de onde vem essa função? Mostre também o código do pai do `NumerosParaMarcar`.

Comment: o problema deve estar na lógica o marcaNumero eu fiz um exemplo e não tive renderização como você demonstrou na figura.

Comment: Pensei nisso agorinha, nao coloquei o MarcaNumero... vou por agora!! , tem como me mostrar eesse exemplo @novic

Comment: Adicionei o código principal da montagem dos componentes!! Obg!!!

Comment: o seu código está totalmente estranho, aonde você consegue pegar `list` dentro de um componente que marca? acredito ser ai o problema, eu mesmo criei uma resposta e não tem esse problema, mas, está oculta e o seu código não conseguimos reproduzir

Comment: @novic olá, bem.. minha ideia deveria ser essa e assim o fiz...  o list é incialmente criado com as 60 posições em branco, e a cada clique no numero, eu vou la no list e preencho a posição do numero, 35 na posição 35 (no caso 36, pois inicia em zero correto?... ) a cada numero clicado eu vou la na posição e preencho. essa modificação do preenchimento é ta fazendo ele processar todo o codigo novamente.... vou colocar o código completo!!!

Comment: me ajuda @novic  :(

adicionei o codigo completo

Comment: Eu fiz o código ali logo abaixo, se não levar negativo você pode conferir.

Comment: Masssa.. vou da uma sacada aqui e fazer uns teste, mano obrigado!!! jaja retorno aqui!!! valeu

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127216/discussion-between-renato-muniz-and-novic).

Comment: @novic Olá .. vc acredita que depois de certo trabalho em adaptar para o reac-native, e depois de funcionando continua executando todo o código?? fiquei pasmo man kkk... porém realmente ficou um pouco mais performático, mas se nao executasse tudo novamente  seria bem mais rápido. to cansado :D.. vou deixar aqui o codigo.. valeu

Comment: é alguma coisa que você ainda está errando.

Comment: Nem imagino! se precisar de mais informações to por aqui, obg!
essa versão que postei aqui, foi praticamente o seu.

Answer (score 1):

Estou percebendo que escreveu mais do que precisa, resolvi criar um exemplo mínimo demonstrando a renderização somente do componente clicado, com `useCallback` e `memo` que verifica de uma forma rasa se o valor realmente foi alterado:

```js
const ButtonDefault = window.styled.button`
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: ${props => props.status ? 'yellow' : '#efefef'}
`;

const Button = React.memo((props) => <ButtonDefault {...props}/>);

function App() {
  console.log('clicou');
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(Array(60).fill(false))
  const handleOnClick = React.useCallback((e, index) => {
    let item = [...list];
    item[index] = !item[index];
    setList(item);
  }, [list]);
  return (
    <div>
    <div>
    { list.map((i,x) => 
       <Button onClick={e => handleOnClick(e, x)}
          status={i} key={x}>{(x + 1)}</Button>
      )
    }
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>Quantidade de selecionados: {list.filter(x => x === true).length}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

A cada clique no botão somente ele é alterado, e isso denota desempenho na renderização de componente, não tendo aquelas famosas travadas relatadas na pergunta.

Comment: Outro voto negativo serm explicações

Comment: tbm não sei pq... até pq resolveu para o ambiente web.

Comment: Não tem o porque desse negativo. Além de responder orientou o AP a fazer o mcve.